# how can i set password to my database? and how can i access it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i used V S 2010
and Sql server 2005.......
now i want to know how i can set passord for access my database in sql server
and how can i make a connection of it........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim connectionString = "server=MYSERVER;uid=MYUSERID;pwd=MYPASSWORD"
Dim connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open
```